# How to use getCountFromServer in a Transaction in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a transaction so that every time a document is added, the count is updated based on the latest count. This seems to be the best of both worlds using `increment` and `getCountFromServer` so that you're only charged on writes, and you don't have to deal with the pain and inconsistencies of `increment`.

This is an example of adding a new todo, while simultaneously increasing the user's todo count.

### Firebase JS SDK

The problem seems to be that `getCountFromServer` returns a promise

```
const userRef = doc(db, `users/${uid}`);

const todoRef = doc(collection(db, 'todos'));

const todoQuery = query(
    collection(db, 'todos'),
    where('uid', '==', uid)
);

await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {

    // Should be in transaction
    const todoCountDoc = await getCountFromServer(todoQuery);

    transaction.update(userRef, {
        todoCount: todoCountDoc.data().count + 1
    });
    transaction.set(todoRef, {
        uid,
        text,
        complete: false,
        created: serverTimestamp()
    });
});
```

What I need to do is put this in the transaction:

```
const todoCountDoc = await getCountFromServer(todoQuery);
```

Something like:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
const todoCountDoc = await transaction.get(getCountFromServer(todoQuery));
```

I have a feeling there is no security reason this doesn't work, it is just not implemented in the JS SDK because no one thought about it. Then again, why is `create` not an option but  `set` is . Am I missing something?

### Node JS

This seems to work fine in Node JS, but I want to do this on the frontend:

```
const userRef = db.doc(`users/${uid}`);

const todoRef = db.collection('todos').doc();

const currentCount = db
    .collection('todos')
    .where('uid', '==', uid)
    .count();

db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {

    const todoCountDoc = await transaction.get(currentCount);

    transaction.update(userRef, {
        todoCount: todoCountDoc.data().count + 1
    });
    transaction.create(todoRef, {
        uid,
        text,
        complete: false,
        created: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
});
```

How can I do this on the frontend?

J

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm checking with the client-side SDK team on what the expected behavior is for this use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client-side SDKs for Firestore only support individual document reads inside transactions. There is no way to use a multi-document read (such as a query) as part of a client-side transaction, and this includes count and other aggregation operations (which by their nature always consider multiple documents).

The server-side SDKs for Firestore use pessimistic locking, which *does* allow those to use multi-document reads in a transaction and thus also lets you use count queries in transactions.

There is no way to get this behavior with the client-side SDKs though. So if this is really required for your use-case, consider implementing it server-side and then invoke that from your client (for example in Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).